# How can I make a split-text input placeholder?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do could perhaps best be explained in an image (which I'll include below), but essentially it's a text `input` HTML field which is half a pre-existing value and the other half is replaceable.  I tried adding both a `value` and a `placeholder` field and then separating them via `padding-left` in CSS, but instead the browser (Chrome) just ignores the `placeholder` altogether.

[image: An example image]

Note the separation between the string "turingpages.com/" and "username".  I want to keep "turingpages.com/" un-editable and have "username" act as an HTML5 placeholder.  How could I go about achieving this effect?

Comment: That's true TildalWave, but I don't know if the answer was as good as this one is.  Not to mention, it was over a year ago and perhaps standards had changed since then.  Never wrong to revisit a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it two elements and style it as if they were one..

Put them side by side (*or even better nest them and make the outer a `label` so it will work with clicking*), and make an `input` only for the right element.

```
<label class="group">turingpages.com/<input type="text" placeholder="username"/></label>
```

and

```
label.group{
    line-height:40px;
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
label.group input{
    border:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:0;
    display:inline;
    color:#aaa;
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ahTJv/

Comment: It is a sign-up page, so i doubt someone would copy the link from this place (*my opinion ofcourse*). The OP does not state that as a need though..

Comment: @TildalWave, no worries, just discussing :)

Comment: Right Gaby, I'd have no reason for the user to want the full URL.  Your solution would work just fine.  Thanks!