# How can I apply different style for main and sub text in input placeholder?

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I want to apply different style for main and sub text in input placeholder as below;

[image]

Password text style as;

```
{
    color:#959595;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

(at least 4 characters) sub text style as I want;

```
{
    color:#cfcfcf;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling the placeholder of an input, how can I do this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485247/styling-the-placeholder-of-an-input-how-can-i-do-this)

Comment: `placeholder` cannot be split as it's an attribute not an element...at least AFAIK

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a split-text input placeholder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567828/how-can-i-make-a-split-text-input-placeholder)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk my question is different please read it again. I want to apply different style to each text block

Comment: The only way to do this is with a `contenteditable` element instead of an `<input>`.

Comment: @midstack I know, read that duplicates to learn that it is not possible.

Comment: In addition to asking for something that is not possible, the question tries to use a placeholder *instead of a label*, contrary to what HTML5 says at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check the [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/cotmLpfa/2/)
You can achieve this effect with a little JS work, in a cross browsers manner:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" data-placeholder-note="(at least 4 characters)" />
```

**JS (with jQuery)**

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var note = $('<span />').addClass('placeholder')
        .text(current.data('placeholder-note'))
        .insertAfter(this);
    var origPH = current.attr('placeholder');
    current
        .focus(function(){
            current.attr('placeholder', '');
            note.hide();
        }).blur(function(){
            current.attr('placeholder', origPH);
            note.show();
        });
    note.click(function(){current.focus();});
});
```

**CSS**

```
input {
    position:relative;
    font-size:18px;
    width:220px;
    padding:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
span.placeholder {
    font-size:12px;
    position:relative;
    left:-135px;
    color:#bbb;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can apply a class to the input elements:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="subtext"></input>
<input type="text" class="pass" placeholder="password"></input>
```

You have to combine the class with the pseudo element

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {    color:#cfcfcf;font-size: 14px; }
input::-moz-placeholder {    color:#cfcfcf;font-size: 14px;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {    color:#cfcfcf;font-size: 14px; }
input:-moz-placeholder {    color:#cfcfcf;font-size: 14px; }

input.pass::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#959595;font-size: 16px; }
input.pass::-moz-placeholder { color:#959595;font-size: 16px;; }
input.pass:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#959595;font-size: 16px; }
input.pass:-moz-placeholder { color:#959595;font-size: 16px; }
```